# Cannot make a directory through php inside mounted s3 bucket

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, s3fs

I have successfully mounted the s3 with the **-o allow_other** option and also having **allow_other** enabled in my fuse.conf file. Inside my bucket I have 2 directories.

I am using Laravel and I am trying to copy images inside my bucket and arranging them in different folders.

The issue is that in the first directory of the bucket , i can successfully write images, however , in the second one I cannot make a directory through

> mkdir(pathToMntS3/folderName,0777,true)

php command.

Has anybody encountered this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The S3 folder and its 2 subfolders have 777 permissions and their owner is "root".

I get the following error in the logfile :

> ErrorException: mkdir(): Permission denied

Also tried to changed the owner to www-data , no success.

Also tried mounting with -o umask=022,0070,0000 and 007